# Vectors must be the same lengths error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot `f(x)=5xcos(x)-x` and it's first derivative in same plot for -2pi<= x <=2pi using MATLAB. But I get the folowing error:

> Error using ==> plot Vectors must be the same lengths."

```
y1 = 5.*x.*cos(x)-x;
y2 = diff(y1);
plot(x,y1,'-',x,y2,'-*')
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` takes the pairwise difference between successive elements and is therefore 1-element shorter than the input vector. As a result, if you want to plot it, you'll want to either append (or prepend) a `0` or just plot with one less x

```
plot(x, y1, '-', x, [0, y2], '-*')

% OR
plot(x, y1, '-', x(1:end-1), y2, '-*')
```